# Incomprehensible error when executing simple C program on an embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I just need to execute a simple helloworld program written in C on my embedded linux. I used many cross-compilers to build different toolchains and on a simulator it works.

But on the target system it displays the same error everytime:

```
./helloworld: 1: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

So I decided it's not the binary problem but the system error. I downloaded a binary that works on the target system (a date from a bin directory for example) and then uploaded it back to the target system - and I got the same error when executing newly uploaded binary.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: How are you up/downloading?

Comment: Downloading to the target system - from the target system shell run - wget http://example.com/...binary

Comment: It seems that the shell tries to run it as a shell script.

Comment: Try to run `file helloworld` (either on your embedded system if available or on some other machine). Is it correctly identified as ELF binary executable for the target architecture?

Comment: Ctx, not on the target system: helloworld: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0, not stripped

Comment: Down voter, how about a comment? I am curious about this issue.

Comment: Can you view the file on the target system? I strongly suspect that it is a download issue and wget leaves you with some html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is this is the issue:

```
~ $ wget  http://www.slashdot.org/helloworld
Connecting to www.slashdot.org (216.34.181.48:80)
Connecting to slashdot.org (216.34.181.45:80)
helloworld           100% |**********************|   161k  0:00:00 ETA
~ $ chmod a+x helloworld
~ $ ./helloworld
./helloworld: line 1: syntax error: unexpected newline
~ $
```

Your wget did not really download the binary, but got some html-page back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try to download the binary the other way and reply